# ASUS X750J with graphic GF740m

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have ASUS X750J  with graphic GF740m
ubuntu 13.10  --64
Additional Drivers tool found this driver:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.60-driver.html
After switch on it and reboot, x server don’t start. 
Say me please what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

follow the link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649to install nvidia driver on ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.